MULE Custom connector With JAVA 11 Build failure
I am trying develop a Mule 4.x custom connector using JAVA Mule SDk.
The connector for which I am trying is build is only supporting JAVA 11 at the moment .Thus when I am trying to build the it via maven it is failing. PFB the local configuration I have setup and the error message iam getting.
OS: MAC OS
Installed JAVA version: JAVA 11
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7, mixed mode)

MAVEN version:
Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39)
Maven home: /Users/yadevkrishna.tr/Maven
Java version: 11.0.19, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.7", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"

Mule module parent:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </parent>

Error message during the build
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.util.IntrospectionUtils (file:/Users/dev/.m2/repository/org/mule/runtime/mule-module-extensions-support/4.6.3/mule-module-extensions-support-4.6.3.jar) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.util.IntrospectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[WARNING] diagnostic: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.mule.runtime.ast.extension.api.loader.ASTExtensionResourcesGeneratorAnnotationProcessor' less than -source '11'
[INFO] diagnostic: Note: Starting Resources generator for Extensions
[ERROR] error on execute: use -X to have details 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.991 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-20T12:13:02+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process (process) on project mule-basic-connector: Error executing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reflections/ReflectionUtils: org.reflections.ReflectionUtils -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


Full POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mule.yadev.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-debezium-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
    <packaging>mule-extension</packaging>
    <name>Mule-debezium - Extension</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.debezium>2.7.2.Final</version.debezium>
        <muleJavaEeBomVersion>4.6.0</muleJavaEeBomVersion>
        <mule.sdk.api.version>0.7.0</mule.sdk.api.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
            <artifactId>debezium-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${version.debezium}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
            <artifactId>debezium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.debezium}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
            <artifactId>debezium-connector-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>${version.debezium}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance
I tried different version of JAVA and Mule-module-parent. Still the same error.
maven -X

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process (process) on project mule-debezium-connector: Error executing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reflections/ReflectionUtils: org.reflections.ReflectionUtils -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process (process) on project mule-debezium-connector: Error executing
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)



NoClassDefFoundError org.reflections.ReflectionUtils that seems to be the error. Nobody can help you more because you didn't provide enough information. [edit] the question to add the full pom.xml.

Added POM file for reference

I'm not seeing anything strange there. Try maven with "-X" to see if there is more information about the error.

maven -X  response is also attached

The debezium java sdk version I am using is only Compatible with JAVA 11
